# How can I draw a horizontal line in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to draw a line for a "Total" column in Crystal Reports. Something like this:

```
        ======          
Total    123.00        
        ======
```

Comment: Do you mean in dynamically in code or in statically in the IDE (crw32.exe)?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Insert->Line** and draw the horizontal line where you want it. If you really want a double dashed line, then just draw 2 single dashed lines.

(Picture is from Crystal Reports XI)

[image: Insert-Line]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following in the IDE:

1. right-click the field and select Format Field...
2. select the Border tab
3. Set the Top and Bottom properties to 'Double'
4. Exit and save changes as you go

Answer (score 1):

Right click anywhere in your crystal report, then select insert, then select line so you can draw lines or even tables.